# Rewriting a query without using a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the schema:

```
Part( PID, PName, Producer, Year, Price)
Customer( CID, CName, Province)
Supply(SID, PID, CID, Quantity, Amount, Date)
```

And the query:

```
Select Cname, Province
From Customer c
Where not exists
(Select * from Supply s
join Part p on p.PID = s.PID
Where CID = c.CID 
and p.Producer = 'Apple')
```

How would I go about rewriting this query without a subquery? I've looked at other posts and most mention using a join however I'm confused as to how to approach it.

Comment: there is no CID in supply table then how can you make a join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Select distinct Cname, Province
From Customer c
left join Supply s on s.CID = c.CID
left join Part p on p.PID = s.PID and p.Producer = 'Apple'
where p.PID is null
```

Comment: there is no CID in supply table then how can you make a join?

Comment: @ClarCleetus I think there is a bug in the data structure provided. The `CID` field is used by the query supplied in the OP. I think `C#` is meant to be `CID`!

Comment: then okkkkkk :)

Comment: Similarly, how would I modify this query:

Comment: 'Select cname, Province'
'From Customer c'
'Where exists'
'(Select * from Supply s'
'join Part p on p.pId = s.pId '
'Where CId = c.CId '
'and p.Producer = 'Apple')'
'and Not exists   '
'(Select * from Supply n'
' join Part nap on nap.pId = n.pId '
'Where CId = c.CId '
' and nap.Producer != 'Apple')'

Comment: @Shpanders Well, that's a different question. It is generally discouraged here in SO to answer questions in comments. Try writing a new post instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **left join**

```
SELECT Cname, Province
FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN  Supply s ON c.id = s.id
JOIN Part p on p.PID = s.PID
WHERE s.Producer = 'Apple'
AND s.id is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
Select Cname, Province
From Customer c
-- join whatever the table that you have common customer id
left join Supply s s.cid = c.cid
join Part p on p.PID = s.PID and  p.Producer = 'Apple'
where s.cid is null
```